# ReactJs - onClick doesn't seem to work on a button HTML tag

Tags: html, reactjs, onclick

I have this simple piece of code in my ReactJs app:

```
import React from 'react'

import '../../../assets/styles/authentication/login.css'
import '../../../assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css'

import { login } from './login_form_actions.js'

export default class LoginForm extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            email : { email: "" },
            password : { password: "" }
        }
        this.handle_sign_in_click = this.handle_sign_in_click.bind(this)
    }

    handle_sign_in_click(e) {
        console.log(e, this.state.email, this.state.password)
        login(this.state.email, this.state.password)
    }

    render() {
        return (
                <div className="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 form-box">
                    <div className="form-auth">
                        <form className="login-form">
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <label className="sr-only" htmlFor="form-username">Email</label>
                                <input type="text" name="form-username" placeholder="Email..."
                                       className="form-username form-control" id="form-username"
                                       onChange={(event) => this.setState({email:event.target.value})}/>
                            </div>
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <label className="sr-only" htmlFor="form-password">Password</label>
                                <input type="password" name="form-password" placeholder="Password..."
                                       className="form-password form-control" id="form-password"
                                       onChange={(event) => this.setState({password:event.target.value})}/>
                            </div>
                            <button className="btn" onClick={this.handle_sign_in_click}>Sign in!</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
        )
    }
}
```

When I click the `Sign In` button, nothing happens for some reason.

I tried to bind the *handle_sign_in_click* as proposed in some other reactjs question (from StackOverflow) but still nothing.. What am I missing here? (next step is to use redux to store the result of the auth on success)

Thanks for any help

## Edit1: Console and  proposition

console:

> react-dom.development.js:22287 Download the React DevTools for a better development experience: react-devtools
>
> authentication:1 [DOM] Input elements should have autocomplete attributes (suggested: "current-password"): ​

However, when I use an `<a/>` instead of `<button/>`, it does work but my design is broken (it's the same at all as when it's a button)

Comment: Anything in the console giving you errors?

Comment: Where is the login implementation? Are you using Redux now?

Comment: Also, you have a form... Where's the `onSubmit`?

Comment: Sounds silly, but is it being recompiled? Check npm / yarn is watching it...

Comment: Could be possible that button event listeners behave differently inside a form. What happens if you give the form an onSubmit event listener and pair it with your handle_sign_in_click(e).

Comment: I don't see any error that should break the code.... can you try silly stuff? change `button` to `a`, just for testing. See if `handle_sign_in_click` is being called.

Comment: I edited the question to add the console.. the `<a/>` solution works but design is broken

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to properly handle basic forms in React (without libs like Formik etc...):

```
import React from 'react';

export default class Form extends React.Component {
  state = { email: '', password: '' };

  handleChange = event => {
    this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
  };

  handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    // login logic here ususally passed down as props from the parent (if not using redux...) so it will be something like this.props.login(...)
    this.setState({ email: '', password: '' });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <input
          name="email"
          type="text"
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          placeholder="email"
          value={this.state.email}
        />
        <input
          name="password"
          type="text"
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          placeholder="password"
          value={this.state.password}
        />
        <input type="submit" />
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried but I get that by changing the button into input: `input is a void element tag and must neither have 'children' nor use 'dangerouslySetInnerHTML'.`

Comment: @Emixam23 That's because you tried to do something like this: `<input type="submit">Sign In</input>` which is not valid syntax. The correct syntax is `<input type="submit" value="Sign In" />`. You could just as easily replace that with a button: `<button type="submit">Sign In</button>`... That's not related to `React` - that's just `html / jsx`

Comment: @Emixam23 In any case here are the official docs for handling forms in React: https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html Good luck...

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a e.preventDefault in your signin handler, check this working [sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-fbha3g?file=index.js)

Comment: @SakoBu Tell me more about it? Thanks gladiatoriitoo, will test